# Windows 10 Home cannot connect to samba share on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, samba

I can't get a new Windows 10 Home laptop to connect to my network shares. On Windows XP I had to enable plain text passwords. I tried that on Windows 10, but it did not work.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
EnablePlainTextPassword=1
```

I also added `AllowInsecureGuestAuth` with no change.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
AllowInsecureGuestAuth=1
```

*SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support* is enabled in Windows features.

I can see the Linux server in the network, but when I try to connect I get these errors:

**Windows Error**

> `System error 86 The specified network password in not correct.`

**Samba Server Error**

> `domain_client_validate: unable to validate password for user USER in`
>   `domain MYDOMAIN to Domain controller \\CONTROLLER Error was`
>   `NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD.`

I can SSH to the server.

I was able to get a Windows 10 desktop to connect about a year ago, but I failed to note what made that one work. Lesson learned. How do I fix it?

Our network is old.

```
Server: SUSE Linux 9.3
Samba: 3.0.9
Domain Controller: Win NT 4.0
```

Here are all the parameters:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters]
    AllowInsecureGuestAuth   = 1
    EnablePlainTextPassword  = 1
    EnableSecuritySignature  = 0
    RequireSecuritySignature = 0
    ServiceDllUnloadOnStop   = 1
    ServiceDll               = %SystemRoot%\System32\wkssvc.dll
```

Comment: I added the following registry key and now I can connect to my shares. But I cannot see the older computers in the network.  D. Hobaugh 41 secs ago
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
LMCompatibilityLevel=1

Comment: ive never had to do any of this in windows 10 to connect to samba. Did you even create users to access the samba share? use `smbpasswd -a user` and give the user a password.

Comment: are you using the windows server to authenticate to the samba server?

Comment: Not using Samba passwords, authenticating against Windows NT server.   Once I added the LMCompatibilityLevel key I was able to Map network drives to the shares.   

The some computers, win nt, 95, xp & linux, won't show up under the file explorer network.  The only computers that show are windows 7 & 10.  I can still connect to the shares by typing the address \\host\share.

Comment: I am able to connect to my Linux Mint OS like I would a Windows PC. However, to do so I had to enter the command provided by @xR34P3Rx. Then you can go to Run and enter "\\linuxcomputername". If done correctly, it should prompt you for a username and password, unless, of course, the `smbpasswd` credentials are the same as the credentials you are currently logged in with.

Comment: i believe you might have to resort to an authentication method that is supported by both Linux and windows. like RADIUS.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may break future versions of Windows Server that your computer may try to connect to, you can try to *force* SMB1 (not recommended).

1. Open up an Administrative Powershell (or Command Prompt) session (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Execute the following two commands, then reboot:

   ```
   sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/nsi 
   sc.exe config mrxsmb20 start= disabled
   ```
3. Try accessing the shares again, using the username/password combo you setup already.

Reference (and how to reverse): [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2696547)